# Is it possible to show/hide some city names in Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am quite a new to Google Maps. I am working on a historical project using Google Maps API v3. According to historical situation, I need only some city names to be visible on the map.

Is is possible to show some city names on the map and to hide all others? Also, is it possible to rename certain city, eg. to display different name from nowadays?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I think this will solve my problem with the city names.

Comment: @geocodezip Do you have any reference of example where cities are not displayed ? I'm trying to achieve this.